# How to exclude one value from a grouping sum, based on a value of another field?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

How do I exclude one value from a grouping sum, based on a value of another field?

ie  I open Report=> Report Properties=>Code and insert my Custom Code, but how would I change the below code to exclude a numeric value of another field for the below case?

```
Public Function ChangeWord(ByVal s As String) As String
   Dim strBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder(s)
   If s.Contains("Others") Then
      strBuilder.Replace("Others", "Other NOT INCL")
      Return strBuilder.ToString()
      Else : Return s
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: The tried the below code(s) and the report runs, but the values are not affected in either of both cases. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to exclude a numeric value from a sum where the string value of a cell on the same row includes "Others", and that the function you've supplied is used as the grouping criteria for a table in the report. Apologies if this isn't correct.

It's not going to be possible to do this without using a second piece of logic, either a function or an `Iif` condition. I don't have SSRS available to test this at the moment, but (assuming your value column is an integer, the code will look something like:

```
Public Function ExcludeOthers(rowDesc As String, rowVal as integer)
    if ChangeWord(rowDesc) = "Other NOT INCL"
        Return 0
    else
        Return rowVal
    end if
End Function
```

Then, in the cell where you want the conditional sum to appear:

```
=Sum(ExcludeOthers(Fields!desc.Value,Fields!val.Value))
```

Alternatively, you could do this without the function by using `Iif` in the cell where the conditional sum will appear:

```
=Sum(Iif(ChangeWord(Fields!desc.Value) = "Other NOT INCL",0,Fields!desc.Value))
```

Depending on the nature of your source data, you could also do this by adding calculated columns to the report's source query.

I would favour the second or third option - custom code seems like overkill for this purpose.